# Java Calendar Comparison methods not returning proper results

Tags: java, object, calendar, comparison, compareto

I'm currently having very odd behavior when doing comparisons on calendar objects.

I have a method that is to determine if the current date `asOfDate` is after 31-DEC-13 `lastDayOfDec13`. The `asOfDate` = 09-JAN-14. I've used similar comparison methods before but I'm not sure why this isn't working at all.

09-JAN-14 is definitely after 31-DEC-13 but it is returning false.

My code is below:

```
private Boolean isTodayAfterDec2013() throws Exception {
    Calendar asOfDate = getAsOfDate();

    Calendar lastDayOfDec13 = getAsOfDate();
    lastDayOfDec13.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
    lastDayOfDec13.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    lastDayOfDec13.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);

    System.out.println("lastDayOfDec13 "+CommonUtils.getDatebaseFormattedDate(lastDayOfDec13));
    System.out.println("asOfDate "+CommonUtils.getDatebaseFormattedDate(asOfDate));

    System.out.println("asOfDate.after(lastDayOfDec13) " + asOfDate.after(lastDayOfDec13));
    System.out.println("asOfDate.compareTo(lastDayOfDec13) " + asOfDate.compareTo(lastDayOfDec13));

    if(asOfDate.after(lastDayOfDec13)) {
        System.out.println("Today is after 31-DEC-13");
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

And my console is printing:

lastDayOfDec13 31-DEC-13

asOfDate 09-JAN-14

asOfDate.after(lastDayOfDec13) false

asOfDate.compareTo(lastDayOfDec13) -1

Is there something about the calendar object that I don't understand? The year should be working fine. Also, my requirement is to use Calendar objects, I cannot use JODA or any outside libraries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  The only thing I don't have is the value returned by `getAsOfDate()`.  Try using a `SimpleDateFormat` to format the values more fully so you can see the full year...

Comment: are the two Calendars `GregorianCalendar`?

Comment: Calendar compares time. What does getTime() output for both calendars?

Comment: The getTime() is printing:

`lastDayOfDec13 getTime = Tue Dec 31 00:00:00 CST 2013`

`asOfDate getTime = Tue Jan 09 00:00:00 CST 14`

Comment: Thanks BevynQ for the lead. I've determined that its the way I'm setting the year. It should be `lastDayOfDec13.set(Calendar.YEAR, 13);`

Comment: This is confusing. I think you mean: You have used lastDayOfDec13.set(Calendar.YEAR, 13) instead of the year 2013 given in your code extract above?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getAsOfDate()` must be wrong...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Calendar asOfDate = Calendar.getInstance();
  asOfDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
  asOfDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
  asOfDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);

  Calendar lastDayOfDec13 = Calendar.getInstance();
  lastDayOfDec13.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
  lastDayOfDec13.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
  lastDayOfDec13.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
  // System.out.println("lastDayOfDec13 "+CommonUtils.getDatebaseFormattedDate(lastDayOfDec13));
  // System.out.println("asOfDate "+CommonUtils.getDatebaseFormattedDate(asOfDate));

  System.out.println("asOfDate.after(lastDayOfDec13) " + asOfDate.after(lastDayOfDec13));
  System.out.println("asOfDate.compareTo(lastDayOfDec13) " + asOfDate.compareTo(lastDayOfDec13));

  if(asOfDate.after(lastDayOfDec13)) {
      System.out.println("Today is after 31-DEC-13");
  }
}
```

Outputs

```
asOfDate.after(lastDayOfDec13) true
asOfDate.compareTo(lastDayOfDec13) 1
Today is after 31-DEC-13
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the getAsOfDate() method (which is a common method used across the system) is wrong. I'm also printing the value of asOfDate directly to the console. Do you have any idea what could be happening?